# Trying to install Joomla on a local server

Tags: xampp, wampserver, joomla3.0

[A screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXKee.png)

I have been having the same error all night. Trying to install joomla on XAMPP. I even went ahead to uninstall my xampp and install WAMP and i am still having the same issue. Please help me out.

This is the error message I get:

> Warning
>
> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
> correctly
>
> | Error running C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.1-O\mysql\bin\mysql.exe
> --user=root -- host=localhost --port=3306 --database=bitnami_joomla "--password=****" -e “SOURCE
> C:/Bitnami/WAMPST~1.1-0/apps/joomla/htdocs/INSTAL~1/sql/
> mysql/joomla.sql;": mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command
> line interface can be insecure. . ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 33 in
> file: ‘CA\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.1-O\apps\joomla l \htdocs\INSTAL~
> 1\sql\mysql\joomla.sql': Duplicate entry '1' for key ‘jos_assets.
> PRIMARY’

Comment: Please share the error message in plain text.

Comment: q Warning x

Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly

| Error running C:\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.1-O\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=root --
host=localhost --port=3306 --database=bitnami_joomla "--password=****" -e
“SOURCE C:/Bitnami/WAMPST~1.1-0/apps/joomla/htdocs/INSTAL~1/sql/
mysql/joomla.sql;": mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line
interface can be insecure. .
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 33 in file: ‘CA\Bitnami\WAMPST~1.1-O\apps\joomla l
\htdocs\INSTAL~ 1\sql\mysql\joomla.sql': Duplicate entry '1' for key
‘jos_assets. PRIMARY’

Comment: Looks like you had a previous installation and the entry "1" in the primary key of that table is already used. Try deleting the table before performing the install.

Comment: I just checked and i have seen the table but cant seem to understand what i am to delete

Comment: The easiest way should be to delete the whole table (or at least all rows in it) and then reinstall.